# exception error in YCSB load command

Tags: cassandra-2.0, ycsb

I am trying to run `YCSB` load command but getting below error after 310 seconds. I have set my cassandra.yaml to following configurations:

```
listen_address : localhost
seeds : 127.0.0.1
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_address : localhost
```

I also tried changing the `rpc` address to `localhost` but still getting the same error. Can someone please help me with this?

```
Loading workload...
Starting test.
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/ycsb-0.3.0/cassandra-binding/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/enter code hereslf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/ycsb-0.3.0/cassandra-binding/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
2015-11-07 21:54:01:591 0 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:54:11:545 10 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:54:21:545 20 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:54:31:545 30 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:54:41:545 40 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:54:51:545 50 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:55:01:545 60 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:55:11:545 70 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:55:21:545 80 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:55:31:545 90 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:55:41:545 100 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:55:51:545 110 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:56:01:545 120 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:56:11:545 130 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:56:21:545 140 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:56:31:545 150 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:56:41:545 160 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:56:51:545 170 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:57:01:545 180 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:57:11:545 190 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:57:21:545 200 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:57:31:545 210 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:57:41:545 220 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:57:51:545 230 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:58:01:545 240 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:58:11:545 250 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:58:21:545 260 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:58:31:545 270 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:58:41:545 280 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:58:51:545 290 sec: 0 operations;
2015-11-07 21:59:01:545 300 sec: 0 operations;
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
Unable to connect to 172.31.18.250 after 300 tries
com.yahoo.ycsb.DBException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:162)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.DBWrapper.init(DBWrapper.java:63)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.ClientThread.run(Client.java:195)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
        at com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10.init(CassandraClient10.java:144)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
        ... 4 more
2015-11-07 21:59:11:545 310 sec: 0 operations;
```